# Cannot resolve symbol hbase

Tags: java, hadoop, intellij-idea, hbase

I am new to HBase, I copied a sample java code from the internet, but I meet an error ***"Cannot resolve symbol hbase"*** when building this sample. I use Gradle to build this sample project and Intellij as IDE. The HBase server is a remoter server and I try to write a put sample at my windows laptop to test the HBase, but I am not familiar with HBase and Gradle, could someone suggest what I have missed?  Here is my code

```java
    import java.io.IOException;

    import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
    import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration;
    import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.TableName;
    import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Connection;
    import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory;
    import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Put;
    import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Table;
    import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes;

    public class PutHbaseClient {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            Configuration conf = HBaseConfiguration.create();

            Connection connection = ConnectionFactory.createConnection(conf);
            Table table = connection.getTable(TableName.valueOf("test"));
            try {
                /*
                 * Put operations for a single row. To perform a
                 * Put, instantiate a Put object with the row to insert to and for
                 * each column to be inserted, execute addcolumn.
                 */
                Put put1 = new Put(Bytes.toBytes("row1"));
                Put put2 = new Put(Bytes.toBytes("row2"));
                Put put3 = new Put(Bytes.toBytes("row3"));
                put1.addColumn(Bytes.toBytes("cf"), Bytes.toBytes("qual1"),
                        Bytes.toBytes("ValueOneForPut1Qual1"));
                put2.addColumn(Bytes.toBytes("cf"), Bytes.toBytes("qual1"),
                        Bytes.toBytes("ValueOneForPut2Qual1"));
                put3.addColumn(Bytes.toBytes("cf"), Bytes.toBytes("qual1"),
                        Bytes.toBytes("ValueOneForPut2Qual1"));
                put1.addColumn(Bytes.toBytes("cf"), Bytes.toBytes("qual2"),
                        Bytes.toBytes("ValueOneForPut1Qual2"));
                put2.addColumn(Bytes.toBytes("cf"), Bytes.toBytes("qual2"),
                        Bytes.toBytes("ValueOneForPut2Qual2"));
                put3.addColumn(Bytes.toBytes("cf"), Bytes.toBytes("qual2"),
                        Bytes.toBytes("ValueOneForPut3Qual3"));
                table.put(put1);
                table.put(put2);
                table.put(put3);
            } finally {
                table.close();
                connection.close();
            }
        }

    }
```

Here is my build.gradle

```
 plugins {
    id 'java'
}

group 'gid'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()

}

dependencies {

    compile group: 'org.apache.hadoop', name: 'hadoop-common', version:'2.7.3'

    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}
```

[image: errors shown in IDE]

Comment: Please include the complete compilation error message, and indicate which line of your code that it occurs on.  (I don't believe it is "Cannot resolve symbol HBase" because 1) your code doesn't use that symbol and 2) there is no `HBase` class in the Hadoop javadocs.)

Comment: @StephenC  the error is shown at 'import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes' where the HBase shown as red in intellij,  seems like I missed some dependencies, I just don't know which are missing and how to add them

Comment: Please include the **complete compilation error message**, and indicate which line of your code that it occurs on.  **Put it into the question.**   Note that the symbol `HBase` does not appear in the line you indicated.  And `hbase` and `HBase` are not the same symbol!

Comment: @StephenC picture added

Comment: So the symbol is `hbase` not `HBase` .... sigh.  For future reference, you should NOT post your error messages as screenshots; see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors

Comment: @StephenC apologies for the mistyped

Comment: Please try "compile 'org.apache.hbase:hbase-zookeeper:2.2.1'"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to a JAR finder site, the `org.apache.hadoop.hbase.TableName` class is in the hbase-common JAR file.

That means that the dependency that you have in your build.gradle file *should* work.   However, I don't think that the version number is correct.  The most recent 2.x version in Maven Central is 2.2.2.  (And 3.0.0-SNAPSHOT is not there ... naturally ... because Maven Central doesn't host SNAPSHOT artifacts!)

However, I recommend that you do what the HBase Documentation says ([here](https://hbase.apache.org/book.html#config.files)):

> "For Java applications using Maven, including the `hbase-shaded-client` module is the recommended dependency when connecting to a cluster."

The corresponding Gradle dependency is:

```
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hbase/hbase-shaded-client
compile group: 'org.apache.hbase', name: 'hbase-shaded-client', version: '2.2.2'
```

---

I am not familiar with Gradle, but I expect that there was another error message saying that it couldn't resolve the dependency for hbase-common version 2.7.3.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this in your gradle dependency:

```
compile 'org.apache.hbase:hbase:3.0.0-SNAPSHOT'
```

Comment: when I added this in my gradle dependency,  I got "Could not resolve: org.apache.hbase:hbase:3.0.0-SNAPSHOT"